# Recursion with pointer and memory leak

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, recursion

I have tried to write a simple program that converts numbers to words (i.e it converts 123 to one hundred twenty three). The code compiles completely. The code uses pointer and recursion, which I always find tricky, in terms of memory management, in c++. Could any one point out if following code can have a memory leak when its executed? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
char *convert_number(int, int);

const char *tens[]={"","ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
const char *words[]={"zero","one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine","ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen", "eighteen","ninteen"};
const char *place[]={"","thouands","million","billion","trillion"};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
int number,conv_num,places;
places=1;
char *string= new char[1000];
char *temp_string = new char[100];
cout<<"Enter a number:";
cin>>number;
string = convert_number(number,0);
cout<<"The word is :"<<string<<endl;
}

char *convert_number(int number,int places)
{
int divisor;
char *word;
int conv_num;
char *temp_string = new char[100];
word = new char[100];
divisor=10;

if (number>=1000)
{   
    conv_num = number % 1000;
    number = (number-conv_num)/1000;
    places++;
    temp_string = convert_number(number,places);    
    word = strcat(word, temp_string);
    word = strcat(word, place[places]);
    word =strcat(word," ");
}
else
{
    conv_num = number;
}
if (conv_num>=100)
{
    word =strcat(word,words[conv_num/100]);
    word =strcat(word," hundred ");
    conv_num=conv_num%100;
}

if(conv_num >=20)
{
 word=strcat(word,tens[conv_num/10]);
 word =strcat(word," ");
 if(conv_num%divisor>=1)
 {
    word=strcat(word,words[conv_num%divisor]);  
    word =strcat(word," ");
  }
}

if(conv_num<20) 
{ 
    word=strcat(word,words[conv_num]);
    word =strcat(word," ");
}       
delete[] temp_string;       
return word;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  If so you should tag it with the homework tag.  Also, is there any reason why you `#include <string>` and then use `char*` for your strings?  Also finally, `const char *place[]` probably doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Thanks. This is not a homework problem, I am just trying to learn memory management with a known problem using recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Could any one point out if following code can have a memory leak when its executed?"

Yes, it can.

```
char *temp_string = new char[100];  // first assignment

[...]

if (number>=1000)
{   
[...]
    temp_string = convert_number(number,places);
```

When you re-assign temp_string this way, the memory from the first assignment becomes inaccessible, and it has not been freed.  You should `delete[]` that first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am just starting on C++ and trying to learn memory management. I changed `char *temp_string = new char[100];` with `char *temp_string;` and removed the `delete[] temp_string` statement and the program runs without any error. Does this solve all the problems?

Comment: You do the same thing with variable `string` and `word`, did you change those as well?  Also, just FYI, you can use Valgrind to check these sorts of things automatically.

Comment: I did the same thing with `string` but with tried same thing with `word` it gives me a bus error.
I'll try Valgrind, thanks for he info.
I am trying to understand how these pointers work when function call creates a stack and how it should be freed with the function returns.

Comment: @DangerousScholar: you don't *didn't* do the same thing with `word`; *strcat* returns the address of the 1st arg, so nothing is lost WRT `word` (but it's usual to not use the return value, since it is redundant). WRT your changes for `temp_string`, you do still need to `delete` it somewhere *if* you assign it to the return value of convert_number(), since that value was allocated with `new`. I recommend you take this to http://cboard.cprogramming.com/ since this isn't really the place for back and forth; they'll squeal about the mix of C and C++ but que sera...mention it is a cross-post too ;)